# Inductive step assumption for all numbers up to $n$

Tags: induction

I know that the inductive step should be "for all $n$ (if $P(n)$ then $P(n+1)$)" and NOT "if  (for all $n$ $(P(n)$)) then (for all $n$ ($P(n+1)$))" - [see this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/186666).

But can it be like "if (for all $i$, where $i = 1, \ldots, n$, ($P(i)$)) then $P(n+1)$)"?

Comment: You might want to search for the difference between strong induction and weak induction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it can. It is called strong induction.

Thanks to [Raj](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/115172/raj), I found answer to my question here: [difference between simple induction and strong induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/517440/149347).